# How to store values in metavalue

Tags: sql

I am making jobseeker website and there i had created candidate profile page manually but the problem is my theme getting search and all home page showing result of listing from my theme default profile page.

Now i am trying to interlink my own candidate table with theme default table.

the default candidate data is been stored in database as post type :resume.

How can i store my own data in postmeta.

Please help.

If you need more expalnation please reply. i will explain it.

Comment: You definitely need to clarify the problem. You also need to state what tools you are using, such as what SQL you are using.